# How do I delete the last two numbers after the decimal place?

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a string like this 21600.00 how do I delete 00 after the dot?
I've tried it like this

```
replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
```

but '.00' is not erased, so the assumption that I expect is like this 21,600 or 8,000 etc.

Comment: You can use Math.trunc() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function to remove `.00` This will show the exact number without any zeros added.

> If you want to convert back to string format you can use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) to do that.

> If you want to add commas format you can use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Run snippet below.

```js
let string = '21600.00'

//Use parse Int
let int = parseInt(string)

console.log(int.toString()) //Returns string
console.log(int) //Returns number
console.log(int.toLocaleString()) //Returns number with comma added
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try any of these:

```js
const str = '21600.00'
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(str));
console.log(Number(str).toLocaleString('en-US'))
console.log(str.slice(0,-3))
console.log(str.split('.')[0])
console.log(str.substring(0, str.indexOf('.')))
console.log(`${Math.round(str)}`)
console.log(`${Math.trunc(str)}`)
console.log(`${parseInt(str)}`)
console.log(Number(str).toFixed())
```

Comment: Only the last one actually yields the expected output. There’s a reason the OP has `(\d{3})+` in their regex.

Comment: .toFixed() also rounds, you can also use this(If rounding is not a issue.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```js
var decimal = 21600.00;
var numString = decimal.toString().split('.')[0];
var integer = parseInt(numString);
console.log(integer);
console.log(Number(numString).toLocaleString('en-US'));
```